# How to load google fonts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-font-api

I loaded d dynamic list of `web fonts` offered by the `Google Web Fonts service` and place it in a select list ,like :

```
$.get("https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=AIzaSyChZeTZ-DzMW-45IUBXUSuBha9MWEiXXtI", 
     {}, function (data) {
     $.each(data.items, function (index, value) {
        $('#fonts').append($("<option></option>")
                   .attr("value", value.family)
                   .text(value.family);
    });
```

Now what i want is to load each `font` when user select it from the select list and for this i tried :

```
$("#fonts").live({ change: function () { 
    $.get("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=" + $(this).val(), {}, 
    function () { alert("font loaded"); }); } });
```

but unfortunately this is not working can anybody please help me out?

Comment: fonts are not applying because they are not loading on get request

Comment: Yes, "google-app-engine" starts with "google". That's all it has in common with your question, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second get request simply returns the needed CSS to load the webfont.

You should either embed that on the page, or easier add a link tag to the page content that will load the google style.

Then you will also need to set the font-family wherever it's used...

Something like that:

```
$("#fonts").live('change', function () { 

    $('body').append("<link rel='stylesheet' id='colorbox-css'  href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=" + escape($(this).val()) +"' type='text/css' media='all' />");

    $('body').css({'font-family':'"'+$(this).val()+'"'})

});



$.get("https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=AIzaSyChZeTZ-DzMW-45IUBXUSuBha9MWEiXXtI",  {}, function (data) {

    $.each(data.items, function (index, value) {
            $('#fonts').append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value", value.family)
                    .text(value.family));
                    });


});
```

Note: `escape` is also used to generate the url in case it need to be url-encoded